# Random seed produces different number as expected

Tags: java, random-seed

For my assignment, I need to generate an array of integers containing different 4 digits using Random(seed). Note that the `generateSecretDigits` method was started in class, but had to be completed at home (I cannot remember which part was done in class).

My professor gave us examples to check if our method works. Although my program generates a code of 4-digits, it does not display the same array of integers as the examples provided. Could someone please help me find the error?

Examples provided:

- generateSecretDigits(45) returns the array {9, 1, 0, 7}
- generateSecretDigits(987) returns the array {5, 8, 9, 7}

My code:

```
// Declare the required import statements

import java.util.Random;

public class BullsAndCows {
  public static void main (String[] args) {

    int[] y = generateSecretDigits(45);

    for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(y[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
  }


  // A method that randomly generates a secret 4-digits number 

  public static int[] generateSecretDigits(int x) {

    /* Declare and initialize an array
     * Assign a default value that is not between 0 and 9 inclusively to each element of the array */

    int[] secretDigits = new int[4];
    secretDigits[0] = 10;
    secretDigits[1] = 10;
    secretDigits[2] = 10;
    secretDigits[3] = 10;

    // Generate a number between 0 and 9 inclusively with the provided seed

    int seed = x;
    Random digit = new Random(seed);

    for (int i = 0; i < secretDigits.length; i++) {

      int secret = digit.nextInt(9);

      // Assign a value to each element of the array

      /* The contains() method takes as input an array of integers and a 
       * specific integer. The method returns true or false depending if an 
       * element is contained within a given array. Note that I have tested 
       * the contains() method and it works perfectly */

      if (contains(secretDigits, secret) == false) {

        secretDigits[i] =  secret;
      }

      else {

        i--;
      }
    }

    return secretDigits;
  }
```

Comment: `nextInt(10)` to get [0, 9] range, the bound is not inclusive

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I thought the 9 was included when using nextInt(9). Thanks a lot

Comment: @KarolDowbecki If I would have used nextInt(100) + 1 is the range [1, 100[ ?

Comment: Yes, you should use `nextInt(bound)` to get the range and then add or subtract to move it around e.g. introducing minimum value like you did with `+1`

Answer (score 0):

`Random` is a [pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) which outputs number sequence using seed, addition and multiplication. Looking at OpenJDK 11 `Random` class the formula is:

```
nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
```

where `multiplier`, `addend` and `mask` are constants:

```
private static final long multiplier = 0x5DEECE66DL;
private static final long addend = 0xBL;
private static final long mask = (1L << 48) - 1;
```

Unless you change the formula or the constants:

- [Seed 45 will produce: 9, 1, 1, 0](https://ideone.com/z02QyH)
- [Seed 987 will produce: 5, 8, 8, 9](https://ideone.com/yQggzJ)

Either there is an error in the problem description or you have to implement the pseudorandom number generator yourself to output specific digits.